# How to set the order of dropdown list items according to their ID numbers in GeoJSON properties

Tags: javascript, leaflet

It is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/d8yga33f/
I need to organize an order of items in my selector according to the ID numbers in the GeoJSON file. It is a part of my code where the items appear in the list:

```
map.on("layeradd", function(e) {
    if(!e.layer.options) {
    return;
  }

    if((e.layer.options.id != "markerLayer1") && (e.layer.options.id != "markerLayer2")) {
    return;
  }

  var markers = e.layer.getLayers();

  var mySelector = $("#mySelector");

  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    mySelector.append("<option value='" + L.stamp(markers[i]) + "'>" + markers[i].feature.properties.name + "</option>");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
map.on("layeradd", function(e) {
  // ...
  var markers = e.layer.getLayers();

  // Get the dropdown
  var mySelector = $("#mySelector");

  markers.sort(function(a,b) {
    // get the ids, and parse them as int
    var aId = parseInt(a.feature.properties.id,10),
        bId = parseInt(b.feature.properties.id,10);
    return aId < bId ? -1 : aId > bId ? 1 : 0
  }).forEach(function(marker) {
    mySelector.append("<option value='" 
        + L.stamp(marker) + "'>" 
        + marker.feature.properties.id // I added the marker id
        + '. ' 
        + marker.feature.properties.name 
        + "</option>");
  })
});
```

See [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cl3MM/Ldb2sf80/1/)